# Problems with Interpolation & Evaluation using scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I have an array which is (15, 8575) and is, basically, 8575 gaussians stacked together (all slightly different). I need to turn this in to an array which is (15, 127181) for convolution with another array. After some searching, I found a question here which appeared to be similar to my problem and suggested using scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline to interpolate the data and then evaluate the function to a larger array.

This seems to work fine for interpolation (at least I don't get error messages, but have no idea if the function is right), but I can't seem to get it to evaluate the function without producing errors. I'm sure there's something obvious I'm missing, but can't see it. The relevant code is this:

```
apoLSF_wavelen = np.zeros(len(apoLSF[0]))
for i in range(len(apoLSF[0])):
    apoLSF_wavelen[i] = 10**(apoLSF_l_s + apoLSF_l_d * i)
y = np.arange(15)
f_LSF = interp.RectBivariateSpline(y, apoLSF_wavelen, apoLSF)
siu_LSF = f_LSF.ev(y, siu_wavelen)
```

The error I get from the last line is below. The first time I thought I'd gotten the order of the arguments wrong and swapped them around only to find the error remained, but with the numbers swapped.

```
(Pdb) siu_LSF = f_LSF.ev(y, siu_wavelen)
0-th dimension must be fixed to 15 but got 127181
*** error: failed in converting 7th argument `y' of dfitpack.bispeu to     C/Fortran array
(Pdb) siu_LSF = f_LSF.ev(siu_wavelen, y)
0-th dimension must be fixed to 127181 but got 15
*** error: failed in converting 7th argument `y' of dfitpack.bispeu to C/Fortran array
```

My apologies if the above code isn't sufficient to analyse the error, but I didn't want to copy in a load of unnecessary stuff, or if there's an obvious explanation I've overlooked here or elsewhere.

Regards.

Comment: The two arrays `x,y` passed to `.ev(x,y)` must be of the same length (they correspond to asking inteprolation at points `(x[i],y[i]), i=0..n-1`). The message tells you they are not.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm not sure that I fully understand though. So, do x and y (in my case y and siu_wavelen) have to be the same length as each other? If that's the case, then how could I generate an array of (15, 127181) using the interpolation function from an input array (15, 8575)? Is there another interpolation function that works on 2d (or n-d) arrays and allows evaluation with non-square arrays?

Comment: `RectBivariateSpline` can do that. Please see the documentation http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.html